# WPF Path Data creates hole

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create an X symbol.  I have drawn two thick lines that overlap, but WPF removes the intersection of the symbols - I want a solid "X symbol"

[image]

```
 <Path x:Name="CheckIcon"  
      Width="{TemplateBinding Width, Converter={StaticResource mathConverter}, ConverterParameter=*2/3-20}" 
      Height="{TemplateBinding Height, Converter={StaticResource mathConverter}, ConverterParameter=*2/3-20}"  
      Margin="1,1,0,1.5" 
      Opacity="1" 
      Stretch="Fill" 
      Fill="Silver"
      Data="M 0,0 L.2,0 L 1,.8 L .8,1 L 0,.2 L .2, 0 M 1,0 L .8,0 L 0,.8 L .2,1 L 1,.2 L .8, 0"
    />
```

Comment: Looks like you just cut them using intersect method instead of unite. Try again but this time take your two rectangles or whatever you're using, lay them over another again to make your X, then select both and Right Click -> Combine -> Unite, and you're done.

Comment: @ChrisW. With what tool? ExpressionBlend?

Comment: Yea I figured that's what you were using. Or if you're more comfortable with something like Adobe Illustrator that's what I make complex paths in and then export to xaml. Unless you just wanted to punch out straight M/L/X data points and draw it from scratch by hand which I occasionally do for easier shapes also.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use [FillRule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fillrule(v=vs.95).aspx) for this. The [Path Mini-Language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189041(v=vs.95).aspx) page also shows the usage method.

> FillRule
>
> Specifies whether the path uses the EvenOdd or NonZero fill rule value:
>   **F0** specifies the EvenOdd fill rule.
>   **F1** specifies the Nonzero fill rule.
>
> If you omit this command, the path uses the default behavior, which is EvenOdd. If you specify this command, you must **place it first**.

```
<Path x:Name="CheckIcon"  
    Width="{TemplateBinding Width, Converter={StaticResource mathConverter}, ConverterParameter=*2/3-20}" 
    Height="{TemplateBinding Height, Converter={StaticResource mathConverter}, ConverterParameter=*2/3-20}"  
    Margin="1,1,0,1.5" 
    Opacity="1" 
    Stretch="Fill" 
    Fill="Silver"
    Data="F1 M 0,0 L.2,0 L 1,.8 L .8,1 L 0,.2 L .2, 0 M 1,0 L .8,0 L 0,.8 L .2,1 L 1,.2 L .8, 0"
/>
```

### Another tedious way...

There is another more tedious way, that is to make the whole cross a single polygon. This means that you need to do the maths of the points at the intersection area. Fortunately for you and unfortunately for me, I did all the maths so here it is. (P.S. I can't believe I did all those sin/cos thing LOL!)

```
<Path x:Name="CheckIcon"  
    Width="{TemplateBinding Width, Converter={StaticResource mathConverter}, ConverterParameter=*2/3-20}" 
    Height="{TemplateBinding Height, Converter={StaticResource mathConverter}, ConverterParameter=*2/3-20}"  
    Margin="1,1,0,1.5" 
    Opacity="1" 
    Stretch="Fill" 
    Fill="Silver"
    Data="M 0,.2 L .2,0 L .5,.3 L .8,0 L 1,.2 L .7,.5 L 1,.8 L .8,1 L .5,.7 L .2,1 L 0,.8 L .3,.5 Z"
/>
```

I did not try it though. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 3):

In such a case where the [FillRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.pathgeometry.fillrule?view=netframework-4.8) won't allow filling overlapping area from two geometries, one may use a [CombinedGeometry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.combinedgeometry?view=netframework-4.8) to describe the Path.Data property one piece at a time:

```
<Path Width="100" Height="100" Stretch="Uniform" Fill="Silver">
    <Path.Data>
        <CombinedGeometry>
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <!-- First part of the cross -->
                    <PathFigure>
                        <PolyLineSegment Points=".2,0 1,.8 .8,1 0,.2 .2,0"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
            <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <!-- Second part of the cross -->
                    <PathFigure>
                        <PolyLineSegment Points=".8,0 0,.8 .2,1 1,.2 .8,0"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry>
            </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
        </CombinedGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

The two geometries are combined by default by executing the union, but the [GeometryCombineMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.geometrycombinemode?view=netframework-4.8)  can be specified if another operation is needed.
Result:

[image]

But in the question case, the figure is particular (2 lines crossing), and can be obtained by playing with the stroke property instead of the fill property, this also simplifies the point collection itself:

```
<Path Width="107.1" Height="107.1" Stretch="Uniform" Stroke="Silver" StrokeThickness="28.3">
    <Path.Data>
        <GeometryGroup>
            <LineGeometry StartPoint=".1,.1" EndPoint=".9,.9"/>
            <LineGeometry StartPoint=".9,.1" EndPoint=".1,.9"/>
        </GeometryGroup>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

The result is the same, and this can be simplified further by using the mini-language:

```
<Path Width="107.1" Height="107.1" Stretch="Uniform" Stroke="Silver" StrokeThickness="28.3"
      Data="M .1,.1 L .9,.9 M .9,.1 L .1,.9"/>
```

Value for width, height and stroke thickness have been adjusted (using Pythagoras) because when using lines rather than the question rectangles, the lines is use middle points of rectangles sides.